# How to type a decorator transforming a mandatory keyword arg into an optional keyword arg?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have many functions which share the same structure and base signature:

```py
async def get_stuff_from_external_api(*, client: Client | None, id: int) -> Ressource:
    if not client:
        client = make_client()
    return Ressource(await client.get(id))
```

To DRY my code I extracted this logic into a decorator, both the decorator and the functions now being:

```py
def external_api_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        client = kwargs.pop(client, None)
        if not client:
            client = make_client()
        return await func(*args, client=client, **kwargs)
    return inner

@external_api_decorator
async def get_stuff_from_external_api(*, client: Client, id: int) -> Ressource:
    return Ressource(await client.get(id))
```

My problem is now that I can't properly type `external_api_decorator` to keep both decorated functions initial parameters (`id` in my example) and returned value (`Ressource` in my example).

I have tried many solutions (`Protocol`, `Generic`, `ParamSpec`, ...) but I think I'm stuck on `Concatenate`/`ParamSpec` not supporting keyword arguments. Am I missing something? It looks like a super classic use-case.

Here is [a mypy playground to reproduce](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=ba14f71f92e6cd6a807edfe6af8aafb9).

Comment: Unrelated to question: It's spelled `Resource`, and if you spell it with two `s`'s, you're going to make some future maintainer have a lot of trouble.